# A question about a permutation model

Tags: set-theory

I henceforth would like to use $A$ to denote a set of atoms, $G$ to denote a group (of permutations of sets) and $F$ to denote a normal filter of subgroups of $G$.

In his 1957 article "Zur Axiomatik der Mengenlehre (Fundierungs- und Auswahlaxiom)" on page 198 in section 2.6 Specker defines a model such that there is no injection $A \times A \to \mathcal P(A)$. In his notation $A$ is denoted by $a$, $G$ is denoted by $g$ and the filter $F$ is denoted by $J$.

He takes $G$ to be the set of permutations fixing all but finitely many $a \in A$. He takes $e$ to be a finite subset of $A$ and uses $h(e)$ to denote the set of permutations that fix $e$. Then he defines the filter $J$ to be the set of all subgroups of $G$ that contain an $h(e)$ for some $e$.

Now my question is: Isn't $J$ the whole $\mathcal P (G)$?

And it would seem to me that if we let $G$ be the set of all permutations instead but keep $J$ then we get the same model.

Comment: I got the article by going to the library and copying it using a good old school copy machine. Therefore, unfortunately, I am unaware of an online location where you can get access to the paper to which I can link.

Comment: Is http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19570031302/abstract the paper?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes but it's not freely accessible.

Comment: Okay. It's still worth putting up a link in the post.

Answer (score 1):

$J$ is a collection of subgroups of $G$. Of course $G\in J$, because $J$ is actually a filter of subgroups (closed under finite intersections, and supergroups). It's not $\mathcal P(G)$ because that would contain sets which are not groups.

Recall the definition of $J$: If $H\leq G$ then $H\in J$ if and only if there exists $e$ such that $h(e)\leq H$.

It follows that $\{\rm id\}$ is not in $J$, because there is no finite set $e$ that $h(e)$ is exactly the trivial group.

Comment: @Matt: I edited my answer.

Comment: @Matt: Please don't edit my answers just so you can un-upvote them.